# Hierarchical-DataBinding in TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a class called `ClassWithPupils` which looks like:

```
public class ClassWithPupils : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ClassWithPupils(IClass @class)
        {
            Class = @class;
            Pupils = new ObservableCollection<IPupil>();
        }


        public IClass Class
        {
            get { return Get<IClass>(); }
            set { Set(value); }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<IPupil> Pupils
        {
            get { return Get<ObservableCollection<IPupil>>(); }
            set { Set(value); }
        }
    }
```

And I have a ViewModel which contains an `ObservableCollection<ClassWithPupils>`.

```
private ObservableCollection<ClassWithPupils> classesWithPupils;

public ObservableCollection<ClassWithPupils> ClassesWithPupils
{
    get { return classesWithPupils ?? (classesWithPupils = new ObservableCollection<ClassWithPupils>()); }
}
```

This collection is filled correct with items from a Database.

Now I want to display all items from ClassesWithPupils hierarchical in a `TreeView`.

My View so far looks like:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ClassesWithPupils, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <Label Content="{Binding Class.Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

So the Class-Names are displayed correct.

Unfortunately I have no clue how to bind the Pupils-Collection of each ClassWithPupils-Entry to the correct item in the TreeView as children.

I tried something like:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ClassesWithPupils, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <Label Content="{Binding Class.Name}"/>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Pupils}">
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

With no success...

So my question is: How can I display the Name of the Pupils as children of the classes in the TreeView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at your code I have spotted only one error in binding, that could cause the described problem, you should bind to Pupils inside the hierarchical template like this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ClassesWithPupils, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Pupils}">
            <Label Content="{Binding Class.Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Looks good. And how can I display the class-name at the parent-element?

Comment: Maybe you could printscreen how your treeview looks now, and maybe you could specify more details where do you want the name of class to appear?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't printscreen. My tree now has 2 root nodes with 2 children each. The Name of the Children is displayed correct, but the root-nodes are empty

Comment: Ok. I solved it. Inside the HierarchicalDataTemplate I've added `HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate` and inside there is a Label which is bound to the Name of the Pupil